# spring-security-oauth2 2.0.7 refresh token UserDetailsService Configuration - UserDetailsService is required

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-security-ldap

I would have one question regarding the configuration of spring-security-oauth2 2.0.7 please.
I am doing the Authentication using LDAP via a GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("authorizationRequest")
public class AuthorizationServer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuthorizationServer.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.addViewController("/oauth/confirm_access").setViewName("authorize");
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class JwtConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter() {
            JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
            KeyPair keyPair = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(
                    new ClassPathResource("keystore.jks"), "foobar".toCharArray())
                    .getKeyPair("test");
            converter.setKeyPair(keyPair);
            return converter;
        }

        @Bean
        public JwtTokenStore jwtTokenStore(){
            return new JwtTokenStore(jwtAccessTokenConverter());
        }
    }


    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    public static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter implements EnvironmentAware {

        private static final String ENV_OAUTH = "authentication.oauth.";
        private static final String PROP_CLIENTID = "clientid";
        private static final String PROP_SECRET = "secret";
        private static final String PROP_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = "tokenValidityInSeconds";

        private RelaxedPropertyResolver propertyResolver;

        @Inject
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Inject
        private JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter;

        @Inject
        private JwtTokenStore jwtTokenStore;

        @Inject
        private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

        @Override
        public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
            this.propertyResolver = new RelaxedPropertyResolver(environment, ENV_OAUTH);
        }

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
            DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
            tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
            tokenServices.setTokenStore(jwtTokenStore);
            tokenServices.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
            return tokenServices;
        }


        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager).tokenStore(jwtTokenStore).accessTokenConverter(
                    jwtAccessTokenConverter).userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer)
                throws Exception {
            oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess(
                    "isAuthenticated()");
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients.inMemory()
                    .withClient(propertyResolver.getProperty(PROP_CLIENTID))
                    .scopes("read", "write")
                    .authorities(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN, AuthoritiesConstants.USER)
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token", "password")
                    .secret(propertyResolver.getProperty(PROP_SECRET))
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(propertyResolver.getProperty(PROP_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS, Integer.class, 1800));
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(-10)
    protected static class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access")
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        }

        @Bean
        @Override
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }

        @Bean
        @Override
        public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() throws Exception {
            return super.userDetailsServiceBean();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration extends
            GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth
                    .ldapAuthentication()
                    .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
                    .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
                    .contextSource().ldif("classpath:test-server.ldif");
        }
    }
}
```

While the refresh token works fine with the release 2.0.6 of spring-security-oauth2, it does not work anymore with the version 2.0.7.
As read [here](https://github.com/royclarkson/spring-rest-service-oauth/issues/19), one should set the `AuthenticationManager` to be used when trying to get a new access token during the refresh.

As far as I understand, this has something to do with the [following](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/commit/e303652a911cf0168b5be68383ac120c23ec63b3) change of spring-security-oauth2.

I unfortunately did not manage to set it up properly.

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices#setAuthenticationManager
```

is called and gets an `AuthenticationManager` injected. I an not sure I understand how the `LdapUserDetailsService` is then going to be injected. The only thing I see is that the `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider` is going to be called while trying to re-authenticate the user during the token refresh call.

Can anyone advise me on how to do it please?

ps: The exception I am getting is the following:

```
p.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider : PreAuthenticated authentication request: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken@5775: Principal: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@441d5545: Principal: bob; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER
o.s.s.o.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint  : Handling error: IllegalStateException, UserDetailsService is required.
```

Comment: As described [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/e303652a911cf0168b5be68383ac120c23ec63b3/docs/oauth2.md), `userDetailsService: if you inject a UserDetailsService or if one is configured globally anyway (e.g. in a GlobalAuthenticationManagerConfigurer) then a refresh token grant will contain a check on the user details, to ensure that the account is still active.` I would have expected the `LdapUserDetailsService` to be automatically used.

Comment: So would I (and it works for me). Can you post a complete project?

Comment: @dave-syer, Thanks a lot for your reply. I isolated the problem in the following test project: https://github.com/jhoelter/zaas/tree/master/authserver there is one tag called **spring-security-oauth2-2.0.6** where the refresh token works fine. When switching to 2.0.7 and setting the above described config it crashes. Many Thanks in advance for you help

Comment: example curl request I use: `curl -u testClient localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/token   \
 -d grant_type=refresh_token -d client_id=testClient     \
 -d refresh_token=[jwt-refresh-token]`

Comment: I get an HTTP Status 500, `{"error":"server_error","error_description":"UserDetailsService is required."}`

Comment: user: bob / password: pw

Comment: OK I see the problem. `LdapAuthenticationProvider` is not backed by a `UserDetailsService` so you don't actually have one anywhere (other than an empty delegate in your filter chain). I'll play with it a bit and see if there is a workaround, or a new feature we can add.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, Spring framework is a nightmare! Because I'm using an AuthenticationProvider implementation instead of a UserDetailService, but if I downgrade the library to 2.0.6 like Jereremie says, it's works, but now the login with `grant_type=user_credentials` doesn't work, Spring doesn't map the authorities and I don't know why because the roles are there, it can viewed with any JWT tool when you decode the token.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As advised by Dave Syer, I created a custom `LdapUserDetailsService`.
The working solution can be found under the following [tag](https://github.com/jhoelter/zaas/releases/tag/custom-LdapUserDetailsService).

## Application Context

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:property-placeholder location="application.yml"/>

    <bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
        <constructor-arg value="${authentication.ldap.url}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="userSearch" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="${authentication.ldap.userSearchBase}" />
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="uid={0}" />
        <constructor-arg index="2" ref="contextSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="ldapAuthoritiesPopulator" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="contextSource"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="${authentication.ldap.groupSearchBase}"/>
        <property name="groupSearchFilter" value="${authentication.ldap.groupSearchFilter}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myUserDetailsService"
          class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsService">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="userSearch"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="ldapAuthoritiesPopulator"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

## Properties

```
authentication:
 ldap:
  url: ldap://127.0.0.1:33389/dc=springframework,dc=org
  userSearchBase:
  userDnPatterns: uid={0},ou=people
  groupSearchBase: ou=groups
  groupSearchFilter: (uniqueMember={0})
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue when I was implementing a a OAuth2 server with JWT tokens with a custom `AuthenticationProvider` instead of a `UserDetailsService` implementation to solve login authentications.

But lately I found that the error Spring raises is correct if you want the `refresh_token` working correctly. For an `AuthenticationProvider` implementation is impossible to refresh a token with a `refresh_token`, because in that kind of implementation you have to resolve if the password is correct, but the refresh token doesn't have that information. However, `UserDetailsService` is agnostic of the password.

The version 2.0.6 of `spring-security-oauth2` works because never checks the user grants, just checks if the refresh token is valid (signed with the private key), but, if the user was deleted from the system after a first login, with a refresh token the deleted user will have infinite time access to your system, that is a big security issue.

Take a look to the issue I reported with this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/813

Answer (score 4):

What you need for the OAuth piece is to create an `LdapUserDetailsService` with the same query as you authenticator and inject it into the `AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer`. I don't think there's any support for creating a `UserDetailService` in `@Configuration` style (might be worth opening a ticket for that in JIRA), but it looks like you can do it in XML.

Comment: Hi Dave, Thanks a lot for your feedback. I setup a Custom `LdapUserDetailsService` (using an old style XML ApplicationContext). The implementation can be found under this [tag](https://github.com/jhoelter/zaas/releases/tag/custom-LdapUserDetailsService).

Comment: I will see to create a ticket for this. I find it quite heavy to have to create a second `LdapUserDetailsService` even if one was automatically configured while calling `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder#ldapAuthentication`

Comment: This post helped me a lot. I'm on an older version of Spring Security (1.x) but was having the same problem. I realized we have a @Bean foe UserDetailsService which for everything else seemed to be working. But I needed to add configuration to the Configurer to know about the UserDetailsService. Thanks for this comment, helping years later.