# Spring + Oauth2: how to refresh access token

Tags: rest, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, access-token, spring-security-ldap

I am building rest web services with Spring Boot. Authentication is implemented using Spring Security and OAuth2. Users are authenticated against LDAP server. Here is my websecurityconfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    private RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;
    @Autowired
    private RestAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http

            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(
                    SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/logout").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/ristore/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler());
    }

    @Override  
    @Bean  
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {  
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();  
    }

    @Bean
    public RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler mySuccessHandler(){
        return new RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    }
    @Bean
    public SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler myFailureHandler(){
        return new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource = getSource();
        auth
        .ldapAuthentication()
            .userDnPatterns("cn={0},ou=institution,ou=people")
            .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
            .contextSource(contextSource);
    }
 }
```

Additional config is done in authserverconfig including clientdetailservice.

```
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
     @Autowired
     @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
     private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


     @Override
     public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) 
       throws Exception {
         oauthServer.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
     }

     @Override
     public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
          endpoints.tokenStore(new InMemoryTokenStore())
          .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
     }
     @Override
     public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
          clients
            .inMemory()
            .withClient("ristoreclient")
            .scopes("read")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token", "client_credentials")
            .secret("ristoresecret")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(60);    
      }
 }
```

It works for initial login. However when I try to get a new access token with refresh token when the old expires, I got the error "UserDetailsService is required". After searching for answers online, I found this post with similar problem: [spring-security-oauth2 2.0.7 refresh token UserDetailsService Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30454480/spring-security-oauth2-2-0-7-refresh-token-userdetailsservice-configuration-us). Basically the solution there was to create a custom `LdapUserDetailsService`. Thing is it was set up in xml config instead of java. Besides, it is not clear how and where this class is injected. In this other [case](https://github.com/royclarkson/spring-rest-service-oauth/issues/19), userdetailservice instance is added in auth server endpoint config instead. This article does not provide the implementation of this class.

The idea of having a userdetailservice, in my opinion, is to look up and see if this user is still active before issuing a new access token. What is contradictory is that the request of getting a refresh_token for oauth2 only consists of the following information which does not include username/password.

```
client_id=clientid
client_secret=clientsecret
refresh_token=1/6BMfW9j53gdGImsiyUH5kU5RsR4zwI9lUVX-tqf8JXQ&
grant_type=refresh_token
```

[OAuth2 for a Spring REST](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth2-refresh-token-angular-js)  uses Zuul proxy as a middle layer between front end and web api to handle refresh token which makes the configuration more complex. How should I implement a userdetailsservice for oauth2 in Spring Boot and where should I inject it?