# Understanding Spring Boot's Oauth2 starter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I started off looking at the Oauth2 starter project and minimal configuration.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/tests/annotation/jdbc/src/main/java/demo/Application.java

All the examples either use in memory configuration or jdbc configuration for storing client roles (e.g ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer) . In my case the details should come in LDAP. So I have two questions.

1. How do override the default to go to ldap instead of memory or jdbc.
2. In general , where how do I unravel the Spring Boot thread and read the starter source code and how to change default config ?  All I see is a high level annotation.

org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer

This indirection in Spring Boot makes it extremely difficult to follow and scant documentation doesn't help. Or maybe I am missing something?

thanks !!! this has been bugging me for a while.

Comment: could this be of any help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30454480/spring-security-oauth2-2-0-7-refresh-token-userdetailsservice-configuration-us

Comment: or this "how to implement an OAuth2 authorization server using Spring Security. In particular, I will set up LDAP as the authentication manager" :  https://raymondhlee.wordpress.com/2015/12/05/oauth2-authorization-server-with-spring-security/

Comment: That answers it thanks Alex. But in general , how do you follow Spring Boot code?  How do I mark this answered?

Comment: You can't mark a comment as accepted, and honestly I feel it is too broad for me to actually post an answer. Perhaps you could post your final solution (add an answer yourself) and accept it!

Comment: not sure what you mean by "how do you follow Spring Boot code"

Comment: So all of the Oauth2 server functionality is brought by one annotation. I want to follow the request and see what components get invoked and when. I also want to know what I need to override in my production application. How do I do that? I'm also looking at Apache Oltu , and it is very straight forward, a very procedural code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To implement Oauth2 with LDAP, you may follow this tutorial : https://raymondhlee.wordpress.com/2015/12/05/oauth2-authorization-server-with-spring-security. 
You may also take a look a this other question: [spring-security-oauth2 2.0.7 refresh token UserDetailsService Configuration - UserDetailsService is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30454480/spring-security-oauth2-2-0-7-refresh-token-userdetailsservice-configuration-us)

---

As for your other question "I want to follow the request and see what components get invoked and when": I suggest you add logging.

**(1) Add logging in every method**

**(2) Set log level for security package in `application.properties`:**

```
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
```

**(3) Add `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter`:**

```
@Bean
public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter requestLoggingFilter() {
    LOGGER.info("Creating CommonsRequestLoggingFilter");
    CommonsRequestLoggingFilter crlf = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
    crlf.setIncludeClientInfo(true);
    crlf.setIncludeQueryString(true);
    crlf.setIncludePayload(true);
    return crlf;
}
```

**(4) Add log level for CommonsRequestLoggingFilter (in application.properties):**

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter=DEBUG
```

---

### For the OAuth/LDAP tutorial, here's the notable parts (quoted from https://raymondhlee.wordpress.com/2015/12/05/oauth2-authorization-server-with-spring-security):

> Authorization Server Configuration Below is my implementation of the
>   AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter. The database schema for JDBC
>   client details and token services can be found in here.
>
> ```
> @Configuration
> @EnableAuthorizationServer
> public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
>      @Autowired
>      private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
>      @Autowired
>      private DataSource dataSource;
>      @Override
>      public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
>           endpoints.tokenStore(new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource)).authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
>      }
>      @Override
>      public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
>           clients.jdbc(dataSource);
>       }
>  }
> ```
>
> Login Security Configuration Below is the security configuration
>   handling user authorization.
>
> ```
> @Configuration
> @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE) // note 1
> public class LoginConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
>
>       @Value("${ldap.domain}")
>       private String DOMAIN;
>
>       @Value("${ldap.url}")
>       private String URL;
>
>       @Override
>       protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
>            http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
>
>            // Only requests matching regex are handled by this security configurer
>            http.requestMatchers().regexMatchers("/login", "/login.+", "/oauth/.+", "/j_spring_security_check", "/logout"); //
>
>            AuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint = entryPoint();
>            http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint);
>            http.formLogin(); // note 3i
>            http.addFilter(usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter());
>            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll();
>            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/oauth/**").authenticated();
>            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/j_spring_security_check").anonymous().and().csrf().disable();
>
>       }
>
>       @Override
>       protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder) throws Exception { // note 4
>            authManagerBuilder.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
>       }
>
>       protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
>            return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()));
>       }
>
>       public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
>            ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(DOMAIN, URL);
>            provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
>            provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
>            return provider;
>       }
>
>       private AuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint() {
>            return new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"); 
>       }
>
>       private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter() {
>            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter filter = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter();
>            filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager();
>            AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler("/login?login_error=true");
>            filter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(failureHandler);
>            return filter;
>       }
> }
> ```